# Where to set RecycleView setAdapter for fast loading of images?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I have an app which fetches an Array of image URL's from my FireStore database and set my RecycleView custom adapter to display all the images on App startup. Should this be inside the for loop or outside for fast loading? Below is my current method. Should the `getData()` be inside for loop ?

```java
urlRef.get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    Log.d("FireStore", document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                    ArrayList<String> arrayList = (ArrayList<String>) document.get("url");
                    //Do what you need to do with your ArrayList
                    for (String s : arrayList) {
                        list.add(new Custom_Items(s));
                    }
                }
                getdata();
            } else {
                Log.d("FireStore", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });

private void getdata() {
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(list, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: It should be outside loop only.

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact data you want to get. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 2):

As your response is an array of URLs then you should set adapter to RecyclerView only when entire data (URLs) is ready.

To load images from URL on RecyclerView item use some background thread or you can try [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)